# Binding with a Custom Control and DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I know that this question has been asked over and over and I've incorporated quite a lot of suggested changes to my code but until now nothing seems to work. Basically I want to extend some controls with certain properties. The simplest example is a **TextBox** with a new Property **IsInEditMode**.

```
public class EditableTextBox : TextBox
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInEditModeProperty =
     DependencyProperty.Register("IsInEditMode", typeof(bool), typeof(EditableTextBox),
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, (o, e) => ((EditableTextBox)o).IsInEditModeChanged(e)));

    private void IsInEditModeChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        IsInEditMode = (bool)e.NewValue;
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    public bool IsInEditMode
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsInEditModeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsInEditModeProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

The corresponding DataTemplate

```
<Style TargetType="controls:EditableTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LuculusDarkGrayBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource LuculusBlueBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="controls:EditableTextBox">
                <TextBox x:Name="edTextBox" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}"/>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsInEditMode" Value="False"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" TargetName="edTextBox" />
                        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Arrow" TargetName="edTextBox"/>
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="True" TargetName="edTextBox"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsInEditMode" Value="True"/>
                            <Condition Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" TargetName="edTextBox"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="IsInEditMode" Value="True"/>
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Setter Property="IsReadOnly" Value="False" TargetName="edTextBox"/>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

The control is bound to a viewmodel property like so

```
<controls:EditableTextBox IsInEditMode="{Binding IsInEditMode}"/>
```

The binding doesn't work. If i put boolean values directly in then the behavior is as expected.

Thanks in advance

Jon

Comment: Have to tried  "{Binding IsInEditMode,Mode=Twoway}"  and Implement INPC since you said its a VM property.

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is used in the ViewModel, Mode=TwoWay doesnt change the behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't use IsInEditModeChanged, just delete this part. Also, delete BindableAttribute.

Do not forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your model. I tested this suite and it works fine. Control:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsInEditModeProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("IsInEditMode", typeof(bool), typeof(EditableTextBox),
 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

public bool IsInEditMode
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsInEditModeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsInEditModeProperty, value); }
}
```

Binding for test:

```
<wpfApplication4:EditableTextBox IsInEditMode="{Binding Path=EditMode, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
```

ViewModel:

```
private bool editMode;
public bool EditMode
{
    get { return editMode; }
    set
    {
        editMode = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```